# SQL Joining table and minus based on column data

Tags: sql-server

I have 3 tables,

budget:

[image]

budgetexpense:

[image]

expense:

[image]

What the table means is basically, a user will insert a budget amount for a specific expense category in `budgetexpense`. Then, the sum of this value will be inserted into the `budgetamount` column in the `budget` table. Then, the user will be able to add expenses based on specific categories in `expense` table.

What I want to know, if there is a way to join both `budgetexpense` and `expense` table, and be able to minus the amount from `budgetexpense` with `expense` based on their categories. For example, transport from `budgetexpense` table must only minus with transport from `expense` table.

Apologies if my explanation is a little messy. Let me know and I'll try to explained to you again better.

Comment: Are you familiar with accounting at all? Because this is a rather primitive way of designing a schema to support financial accounts in general. And it really helps to know the relationships between the tables - the primary, foreign, and unique keys. Pictures are not that useful - post DDL / scripts. Do you budget yearly? How do you intend to accommodate that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is another approach that will show the remaining budget even if there were no expenses. Basically, aggregate the expense amounts on expense category and then join budgetexpense to it on category subtracting total expenses from the budget expense amount.

```
SELECT
          bexp.*
        , bexp.amount - COALESCE(bcexp.totalexpenseamount, 0) AS [remainingbudgetamount]
FROM      budgetexpense bexp
LEFT JOIN (
              SELECT
                       budgetcategory
                     , SUM(expenseamount) AS [totalexpenseamount]
              FROM     expense
              GROUP BY budgetcategory
          )              bcexp ON bexp.expensecategory = bcexp.budgetcategory
```

Full demo [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=300a96b77ed21f15374558f1844fd1fd).

If you want to also show records where there is an expense with no corresponding record in the budgetexpense table you need to use a FULL JOIN. I don't know exactly what you want for columns I took a guess; change it up as you need. I also added a join on budgetid which you will need if you have more than one budget.

```
SELECT
          COALESCE(bexp.budgetid, bcexp.budgetid) AS [budgetid]
        , COALESCE(bexp.expensecategory, bcexp.budgetcategory) AS [category]
        , bexp.amount AS [budgetamount]
        , bcexp.totalexpenseamount
        , COALESCE(bexp.amount, 0) - COALESCE(bcexp.totalexpenseamount, 0) AS [remainingbudgetamount]
FROM      budgetexpense bexp
FULL JOIN (
              SELECT
                       budgetid,
                       budgetcategory
                     , SUM(expenseamount) AS [totalexpenseamount]
              FROM     expense
              GROUP BY budgetid
                     , budgetcategory
          )              bcexp ON bexp.budgetid = bcexp.budgetid
                              AND bexp.expensecategory = bcexp.budgetcategory
```

Full demo of that [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=4d32aebac322e9cb6fcb4144bbc60377).

Comment: It's almost the answer I'm looking for. What if I added a record with category "Car" into the Expense table, and the "Car" category has not been added in the budgetexpense table? How do I show this in the select statement table?

Comment: Just took a look. Yea this was what I wanted. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

**Try below query:**

```
;with CTE as(select budgetid,budgetcatagory,sum(expenseamount) expenseamount from expense
group by budgetid,budgetcatagory
)
select a.budgetid,a.amount,a.expensecategory,a.amount-cte.expenseamount RemaningAmount
from budgetexpense a,cte where a.budgetid=cte.budgetid
 and cte.budgetcatagory=a.expensecategory
```

For more clearity [Click Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=6954ea30f0b93d88f5c765a2834923c6)